# If cells of a column equal a certain value, clear content of rows which those cells belong in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I managed to run the script below that clears the cells which have value 'book' in column D, however I want to clear the entire rows to which those cells belong. How can I modify this? I dont want to use `deleteRow()` since it will reduce the number of rows of the sheet.

```
function Remove() {
    var returnSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('xxx');
    var rowCount = returnSheet.getLastRow();

    for (i = rowCount; i > 0; i--) {
        var rrCell = 'D' + i;
        var cell = returnSheet.getRange(rrCell).getValue();
        var range = returnSheet.getRange(rrCell);
        if (cell == 'book' ){
            range.clearContent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var range = returnSheet.getRange(rrCell);
```

With

```
var range = returnSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, returnSheet.getMaxColumns());
// getRange(startRow, startColumn, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns)
```

---

Here's how I would write your function.
This way, there are only a couple of calls to the spreadsheet instead of several for each row. :)

```
function Remove() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('xxx');

    var rangeList = [];

    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if (data[i][3] == 'book') {
        // Arrays are zero-based. The first element is
        // element 0, the second is element 1, etc.
        // D is the fourth column, therefore it's element 3.

            rangeList.push('A' + i + ':Z' + i);
            // Change Z to your last column
        }
    }

    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).clearContent();
}
```

---

#### References

[getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)

[getRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

[RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

[Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

[Batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)